# Get the value to add plus 1 to work in a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following stored procedure and the `UploadCount` column is not adding a +1 value and instead its only putting 1.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Adm].[Proc_Reports]
    (@TestID BIGINT,
     @AgentID BIGINT,
     @AcctMonth BIGINT)
AS
    DECLARE @UploadCount AS BIGINT
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SET @LastUploadDate = 0
    SET @UploadCount = @UploadCount + 1

    INSERT INTO [Adm].[Proc_Reports] (TestID, AgentID, AcctMonth, UploadCount)
    VALUES ((@TestID), (@AgentID), (@AcctMonth), @UploadCount)
END
```

Note: I am trying to write a stored procedure that can check if the value in the `UploadCount` column is 1, and if it is, then update the value changing the 1 to 2 and counting onwards.

Comment: Why do you declare @UploadCount in the beginning?

Comment: You have not given the variable @UploadCount an initial value.

Comment: There is so much wrong with the example code. How can you have a proc named the same as a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use a `MERGE` statement to either `INSERT` a new row or `UPDATE` an existing row, e.g.:

```sql
create procedure [Adm].[Proc_Reports]
(
    @TestID bigint,
    @AgentID bigint,
    @AcctMonth bigint
)
as
begin
    set nocount on
    ;merge into [Adm].[Reports]  as Target
    using (select @TestID, @AgentID, @AcctMonth) as Source (TestID, AgentID, AcctMonth)
    on Target.TestID=Source.TestID
        and Target.AgentID=Source.AgentID
        and Target.AcctMonth=Source.AcctMonth
    when matched then update set UploadCount += 1
    when not matched then
        insert (TestID, AgentID, AcctMonth, UploadCount)
        values (TestID, AgentID, AcctMonth, 1);
end
go
```

This is easier than messing around with SELECT...WITH(ROWLOCK), UPDATE and INSERT statements individually.

REF: [MERGE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I do have a question; if I want the UploadCount "WHEN MATCHED" to be "INSERTED" instead of "UPDATE" the existing row then how would I modify the query. I tried several ways but no luck so far

Comment: It depends on the table constraints. I assumed from your question that the table has a unique index/constraint on `(TestID, AgentID, AcctMonth)` and if that's the case then you won't be able to insert a second row with those same values. If there is not a unique index/constraint on `(TestID, AgentID, AcctMonth)` then the above code will probably be incrementing `UploadCount` on more than one row, which is a problem.

Comment: Thank you. Any suggestions on how to do it? Probably not using MERGE but instead using INSERT with SELECT and a CASE with it....

Comment: There isn't a single statement solution to the problem, I'm afraid. You could do try an `INSERT... SELECT... WHERE NOT EXISTS(...)` followed by an `UPDATE` if no rows were inserted but, depending on the system, that could lead to race conditions. That's why I mentioned `SELECT... WITH(ROWLOCK)` in my answer - race conditions are a consideration, even in RDBMSes.

Comment: Thank you and I will take it from here but I will definitely post it here if it gets resolved